# Unable to run migration in sequelize due to config file

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I am having an issue with my config file
I have it set up to make use of environment variables
It looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  db: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    options: {
      host: process.env.HOST || "127.0.0.1",
      dialect: process.env.DIALECT || "postgres"
      }
    }
  }
```

when I want to run migrations and I am faced with two errors;

1

```
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
```

2

```
ERROR: password authentication failed for user "jioke"
```

My models/index.js file looks like this;

```
var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js');
var db        = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)

....
```

After searching on Google, I created a `.sequelizerc` file.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js')
}
```

My `.env` file looks like this;

```
DB_USER='test'
DB_PASS='test'
DB_NAME='test'
DIALECT='postgres'
```

None of the solutions I found on Google seems to work

The only that one worked; was converting the `config.js` file to `config.json`. But I want to make use of environment variables so I don't commit what I have in my `.env` file.
What is the way around/out of this?
Thanks.

Comment: can u show us ur .env file ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle I've added it.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Ensure to `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of your configuration file for Sequelize.